# Can string formatting be used only in print() function and statements in Python?

Tags: python, string, search, formatting, match

```
iterator, i is "Roster ID 2006 has been deleted"

  if re.match("Roster ID 2006 has been deleted",  i): //works

  if re.match("Roster ID %s has been deleted" % i,  i): //does not seem to work
```

Can I not use string formatting anywhere else except print functions and print statements?

Comment: I suspect that if you tried `print "Roster ID %s has been deleted" % i` at that point in your code, it wouldn't do what you expect either. Print it and see what you get.

Comment: so can i or can i not do it?

Comment: You can. You're just doing it wrong.

Comment: Did you actually _try_ `print` in this situation? Then you'd seen what is actually wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use string formating outside print. Your example does not work beacuse i is the string you are looking for. It should be a year, e.g. 2006

```
i = "Roster ID 2006 has been deleted"
print(re.match("Roster ID 2006 has been deleted",  i))
print(re.match("Roster ID %d has been deleted" % 2006,  i))
```

In both cases we get the following :

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 31), match='Roster ID 2006 has been deleted'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 31), match='Roster ID 2006 has been deleted'>
```

But you are doing this:

```
re.match("Roster ID %s has been deleted" % i,  i)
```

which is same as:

```
re.match("Roster ID Roster ID 2006 has been deleted has been deleted",  i)
# thus you are getting None as a result of the match.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can; but doing `"Roster ID %s has been deleted" % i` will only produce the same thing as in the other line - i.e. `"Roster ID 2006 has been deleted"` - if `i` is the string `"2006"` or something that converts to that string. Since your "working" statement is `if re.match("Roster ID 2006 has been deleted",  i):`, it appears that `i` is actually some long string that you expect to contain `"Roster ID 2006 has been deleted"`. Be sure you have the arguments in the right order:

```
>>> help(re.match)
Help on function match in module re:

match(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.
```